# Get the current post category name inside while loop

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, posts

I created a custom post type "stm_media_gallery"
And three category inside this custom post type.
I want to display category name associated with each post.

```
<?php $gallery_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 
'stm_media_gallery', 'posts_per_page' => -1) );
 if( $gallery_query->have_posts() ) : 
 while( $gallery_query->have_posts() ) : $gallery_query->the_post(); ?>
      --Display post name and its category name
 <?php endif; ?>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: You need [wp_get_post_terms()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) function.

Comment: @Sky This worked man..thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

You just need to put following code inside loop :

```
<div>
<?php 
    foreach((get_the_category()) as $category){
        echo $category->name."<br>";
        echo category_description($category);
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

**Update in existing code**

```
    <?php $gallery_query = new WP_Query( 
      array('post_type' => 'stm_media_gallery',
       'posts_per_page' => -1) );

 if( $gallery_query->have_posts() ) : 
 while( $gallery_query->have_posts() ) : $gallery_query->the_post(); 

    $gallery_category = get_the_category( get_the_ID() );

    the_title( '<h3>', '</h3>' ); 
    echo "<br>";
  <?php foreach ( $gallery_category as $key => $value) { echo $value->category_nicename; } ?>


 <?php endif; ?>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: get_the_category() is for `category` tax only. In this case we need `wp_get_post_terms()`

Comment: when checked "gallery_category" returns empty array

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pre-made WordPress function `the_category( $separator, $parents, $post_id )` to print the post categories as links.

Further information on the WordPress Codex: [Function Reference: the_category](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category)

Edit: Print only the names:

```
$categories = get_the_category();

if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    echo esc_html( $categories->name );   
}
```

Comment: i need post category name not the link

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside While Loop

```
  global $post;
  $postcat = get_the_category( $post->ID );
```